# Reused efi partition in dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, boot-partition

I have dual boot with Windows 10 + Kde neon

1. I installed Windows 10 with default partitions:

   - A Recovery partition.
   - An EFI System Partition.
   - A Microsoft Reserved Partition.
   - A Windows Data Partition or C drive.
2. Ubuntu partitions:

   - /home partition
   - /   partition
   - swap partition

For /boot/efi partition i reused that Windows created is it good idea?or in future I will have troubles?

Comment: yes, there can only be one efi system partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there can only be one EFi system partition.

However, you may have to do some tweaking on some systems to get grub to boot instead of windows.

Comment: For now can run windows and ubuntu without troubles.

Comment: if it is working fine you are good.  on some systems windows keeps overiding grub and you have to do file tweeks to fool windows into setting grub.

Comment: The statement that "there can only be one EFI system partition" is wrong. The [EFI specification](http://www.uefi.org/specifications) is quite clear that there can be multiple ESPs. That said, the Windows installer (at least as of Windows 7; I haven't checked later ones) tends to flake out when multiple ESPs are present, so using multiple ESPs on a computer that boots Windows is inadvisable.

Comment: @Rod can and does  are two separate entities. just because it is allowed doesn't mean it was implemented. you need to step out of theory a bit and step into reality. having more than one is having 2 boot partitions, how to decide which to boot??

Comment: @ravery, EFI systems normally boot by storing information on what boot loader to use in NVRAM. These entries tell the system not just which file to boot, but on which partition the boot file resides. You can examine and manipulate this information via the `efibootmgr` tool in Ubuntu. Of course, there are caveats, like broken EFI implementations on which this doesn't work correctly, but this does work correctly on most recent (~<3-year-old) systems. I have computers with multiple ESPs and can switch between them just fine.

Comment: @rod -- you told me in another post that efi doesn't scan for loaders. you contradict yourself. if it doesn't scan how do you get it to boot a second efi system partition to get  the info n the nvram ?? PS you need to stop attacking me on posts. I have all the down votes I have are from you.

Comment: @ravery, you're mis-representing my comment. I said nothing about scanning in my earlier replies here. As I *explicitly* said, the NVRAM entries can be manipulated by `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu. Please read [Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) for background information. I am not attacking you; I'm correcting your misinformation.

Comment: @Rod -- I can't find the post where you made the comment, but no I am not misrepresenting what you said.  you explicitly said that no efi scans for OS's. you said this after I told you my system scans efi/boot. so how does it find a second efi partiton and boot thefiles there to get them in nvram th first time? nvram only records successful boots.

Comment: @ravery, please read the linked-to article. Adam Williamson's piece explains how EFIs boot quite clearly, and that's not something that's complex enough that it's not suitable for discussion in a comment thread. If you still don't understand it after reading Williamson's piece, feel free to post a question about it. In the meantime, please stop spreading misinformation on this subject.

Comment: I understand,  and implementations vary from computer to computer. when I choose boot options in my system setting it lists boot devices (drives where it found /efi/boot/bootx64.efi and OS's othr efi files found in the efi efi foldr. this list is automatically, updated when I make changes. it also allows me to manual browse for the file I want to launch

Comment: PS -- I read extensively on EFI when trying to dual boot a computer that would only boot from efi/boot/bootx64.efi

Answer (score 2):

The [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is intended to be shared across OSes, and in a simple dual-boot like yours, this is fine. There are a couple of caveats, though:

- **You should disable Fast Startup and Hibernate in Windows** -- These features are likely to cause filesystem corruption on shared partitions, including the ESP. Thus, they should be disabled. See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for details on how to disable these features. Note that the Windows Fast Startup feature is *not* the same as a feature with a similar name in many EFIs; the latter feature typically skips some optional hardware initialization steps in the firmware, which can make booting from external media difficult or impossible. If you can dual-boot with the EFI feature enabled, it should cause no long-term problems.
- **Backing up is important** -- The ESP holds boot loaders for both Windows and Ubuntu. It's therefore an unusually critical part of the disk, and because both OSes can access it, it can be easily damaged by a bug or user error. Therefore, keeping a backup of this partition is important. A file-level backup (using `cp`, `tar`, or `zip` in Ubuntu, for instance) should be adequate.

Comment: sleep mode also cause corruption?

Comment: If you put the computer to sleep in one OS and then wake into the same one, that should cause no problem; but if you put it to sleep in one OS but then boot up into another OS, filesystem corruption can result.